# Toggle Font Awesome Bookmark Icon

Tags: jquery, fonts, icons, toggle

Thank you for all the work you guys do to help this learner!

I'm trying to goggle between an open bookmark fa icon and a closed fa bookmark icon. My code works if I start with a closed icon but not the other way around. How do I fix this?

Thanks :) Any help appreciated!
[Code Here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FO8IP3J9XMQ0)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a pure JavaScript solution, you can toggle both:

```
<i onClick="myBookmark(this)" class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
x.classList.toggle("fa-bookmark-o");
x.classList.toggle("fa-bookmark");
```

Otherwise, if you're looking for a JQuery solution:

```
<i id="bookmark-toggle" onClick="myBookmark(this)" class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
$("#bookmark-toggle").toggleClass("fa-bookmark fa-bookmark-o");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are just toogling the class ***fa-bookmark***, and always keeping the class ***fa-bookmark-o***.

On the font-awesome.min.css the class ***fa-bookmark-o*** is declared after ***fa-bookmark***, so when the both classes are present, the ***fa-bookmark-o*** will always win.

Read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/precedence-css-order-css-matters/), about css order precedence.